# What is the difference between fatal errors and nonfatal runtime error?

Tags: java

" Fatal runtime errors cause programs to
terminate immediately without having successfully performed their Nonfatal
runtime errors allow programs to run to completion, often producing
incorrect results"
I have read this information but  I need examples that illustrate the concept more...

Comment: "*without having successfully performed their Nonfatal runtime errors*" ???

Answer (score 1):

For example `OutOfMemoryError` is rather hard to recover from (if even possible) while it is easy to handle `IllegalArgumentException` by returning information to user .

Answer (score 1):

Fatal error like OutOfMemoryError, VirtualMachineError and so on in general don't assume actions for recovery.

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) say:

*An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.
A method is not required to declare in its throws clause any subclasses of Error that might be thrown during the execution of the method but not caught, since these errors are abnormal conditions that should never occur. That is, Error and its subclasses are regarded as unchecked exceptions for the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions.*

For example if you run recursive task with no base case for break execution.

```
int recursiveSum(int n){
        return n + recursiveSum(n+1);
    }
```

You encounter with StackOverFlowError which means that you fill your stack and JVM can't continue normal execution of your program.

Like another example errors may appear because of hardware or internet connections problems.

But checked exceptions is in general a normal behavior of your program. It's define constraints for users which use your application.